# Search through multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, search

I had a working search function for my news website, but I have been rewriting my code and restructuring my database in order to add more functions. Before, all the info I wanted searched through could be found in one table. Now there is a table for the basic data of a news article, and a second which contains the text (could be multiple rows per article). The first search function was easy:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pages 
WHERE page_status != '99' 
AND (page_title LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($words)."%' OR page_text LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($words)."%') 
ORDER BY page_onlinedate DESC
```

Now I need to query multiple tables, as 'pages.page_text' does not exist anymore. It moved to a second table named 'page_content.content_text', and is linked to 'pages.page_id' with 'page_content.content_page_id'.

I can't find out how to get the results displayed without having duplicates (querying every table once, and as it is possible to have multiple rows in page_content, it could display the same article for example four times if the searched word can be found once in the title and in every text row). I guess it has to be done with table joins, but joins get my really confused.

Once more, my database layout to be clear:

```
PAGES
page_id
page_title
page_onlinedate
...

PAGE_CONTENT
content_id
content_text
content_page_id
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In order to obtain useful answers, you would probably have to provide a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) populated with some sample data to make things more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
select p.*, pc.* 
from pages p join page_content pc on p.page_id = pc.content_page_id 
where p.page_status != '99' 
  and (p.page_title like '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($words) . "%' or pc.content_text like '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($words) . "%') 
group by p.page_id 
order by p.page_onlinedate desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   pages 
WHERE  page_status != '99' 
       AND ( page_title LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($words)."%' 
              OR page_id IN (SELECT content_page_id 
                             FROM   page_content 
                             WHERE 
                 page_text LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($words)."%' 
                            ) ) 
ORDER  BY page_onlinedate DESC
```

Comment: This one goes into an infinite loop. The other answer above works like a charm. Thanks a lot for trying to help though!